# Updating to .NET Standard 2.0 Nuget packages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have updated my nuget packages for an existing project.  I have updated all of my packages, including the .NET Standard 2.0 nuget package.  Now I am getting the error message below.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

I've tried to to clean, rebuild, rebooted, etc.  I've googled and think that this is in reference to the .NET Standard 2.0 nuget package.  I've got some entries in my runtime assembly binding section of my web.config.

I would think that I would need to reference Runtime 4.3.0.0, but I don't see a way to do this.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  TIA.

Comment: Can you share assembly binding section of your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ASP.NET Core, you can set assembly for **System.Runtime** in *system.web section in web.config*. By the way, please configure your *.NetFramework version*, too.

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That is what I thought as well.  Unfortunately, that does not resolve the issue.

Comment: I resolved the initial issue of the app not running by going into web.config and doing some binding redirects.  Unfortunately, a component I have is still complaining.  I'm still working on that one.  :-/

Comment: Like many things, with a little bit of sleep, I was able to see the exact problem and resolve it.  What was the problem?  I misread it last night.  The original error was resolved with a binding redirect on the System.Runtime.  The next problem was a similar one, but I misread it.  The solution was that I needed to set a binding redirect on System.Net.Http.  That is how I solved it.  Thanks.